# Starred tabular environment and centered text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, starred-version

How to make the starred `tabular` to center text:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
        \hline
            Text to be centered \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How is that possible to make the text centered?

Comment: For what is the `\extracolsep{\fill}` used for? Try it without. Also `tabular*` might just extend the table rules but not increase the cell width.

Comment: @MartinScharrer `\extracolsep` is the documented interface to changing `\tabskip` in LaTeX so it wasn't a bad guess even though it doesn't work. (Especially as I don't think any documented use works in this instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be quite the documented interface....

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

{\tabskip=\fill\newskip\tabskip
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}c@{}}
        \hline
            Text to be centered \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}}
\end{document}
```

[image]